# How to get ID from auto pop up drop down in MVC View ?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am developing ASP.NET MVC application.

I have a dropdown not exactly drop down, but I have give the feel of dropdown.

User can add n number of product in the list.

When user start typing in the textbox, the Products which start with entered character are start appearing below to that text box. see the image...

[image]

Its working fine while selecting the item from dropdown.

Now, the problem is comes when I want to get the Product ID's of the Products which have added by user.

I wan to get array of the Product Id's added by user.

My Controller Code

```
  public ActionResult NewvendorList(string term)
        {
            var results = new[] 
             {
            new { id = "1", label = "Suraj Metels" },
            new { id = "2", label = "A.B. Infra" },
            new { id = "3", label = "Momin Brother" },
            new { id = "4", label = "Fort"},
            new { id = "5", label = "Malabar Hill" },
            new { id = "6", label = "A.B.C. Limited" },

            };
            var result3 = results.Where(s => s.label.ToLower().StartsWith(term.ToLower())).Select(w => w).ToList();       
            return Json(result3, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Forms View Code, Jquery code used to fetched the data from Controllers method...

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        var i = 0;


        $("#lnkAddProduct").on("click", function () {
            //$('#ProductId').val("");
            @*var url = "@Url.Content("~/Scripts/GeneralScript.js")";
                 $.getScript(url, function () {
                 });*@
            var d = '<div class="addedProduct "><div class="control-group " style="margin-bottom:10px;"><input type="text" class="ProductName span2 pull-left" id="Product_Name_' + i + '" name="Product_Name" value="" placeholder="start typing to load products" )"/><input type="hidden" class="ProductCode" name="Product_Code" id="ProductCode_' + i + '" value=/><a href="#" class="clsremove font-midium" style="margin-left:5px;margin-top:5px;" id="remove_' + i + '">remove</a></div></div>';
            $('#ProductList').append(d);
            alert("newID:"+i);

            $(".clsremove").unbind("click").click(function () {
                $(this).closest(".addedProduct").remove();
            });


            $('body').delegate(".ProductName", "focusin", function () {
                $(this).autocomplete({
                    source: '@Url.Action("NewvendorList","Product")',

                minLength: 1,

                select: function (evt, ui) {


               $("#Product_Name_"+ i ).val(ui.item.label);


               $("#ProductCode_" + i).val(ui.item.id);

               alert($("ProId" + $("#ProductCode_" + i).val(ui.item.id)));


                }


            });
            });

            i = i + 1;          
        });       
    }); 


</script>
```

How to get thise ID's while saving the Record ?

Comment: please clarify scenario and requirement more. cant get `get the Product ID's of the Products which have added by user`

Answer (score 0):

This might be what u want.

`onclick` of `create` button u call jquery handler and get the values of div or spans, whatever you are using and put all these values in array. then you can assign values of array to some hidden element and access it at controller side on submitting form

```
var ids=[];
$('span[id^=ProductCode]').each(function(){
    ids.push(parseInt($(this).text()));
});
var st=ids.join();
alert(st);
$('#hdn').val(st);
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/pNdY3/1/)